# How do I perform actions while waiting for server response in react native's fetch API?

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

[The React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#handling-the-response) show the following code for React-Native's fetch API:

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
  return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
 }
```

What I'm looking for is the place to put things like a loading script while `fetch` is calling the server, something like the following non-working code:

```
function getMoviesFromApiAsync() {
  return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
    .whileWating(() => {
      // This is the type of thing I want to put into the fetch
      console.log('Waiting for the server response.') 
    })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      return responseJson.movies;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way this is usually solved is by updating the state. Like so:

Fetch:

```
this.setState({isLoading: true});
fetch(url)
.then((response.json()))
.then((responseJson) => this.setState({isLoading: false}));
```

Then in your render method something like this:

```
if (this.state.isLoading){
   return this.myLoadingView();
} else {
   return this.myViewWithCompletedData() 
}
```

Once the fetch is done, the state will update and RN will be smart enough to re render your view.